# Return different results decided by range

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table for scores: 35, 47 etc. how do i return the score (devided with 10) in symbols. for 35 3 stars, for 47 5 stars.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explicitly thinking about ranges, you can use [the `lpad()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions087.htm):

```
select lpad('*', round(your_column/10) '*') from your_table ...
```

This rounds the number of stars to the nearst whole number, which seems to be what you want. You can use ceil, floor or trunc if not. If the rounded/truncated value is zero this will return null.

For example,

```
select lpad('*', 3, '*') from dual;
```

gives

```
***
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use case statement for this:

```
SELECT score,case when score between 0 and 15 then '*'
                  when score between 16 and 30 then '**'
                  when score between 31 and 40 then '***'
             end as 'STARS'
FROM ScoreTable
```

Of course you will have to adjust the ranges for each star since you didn't explain the logic to us. Also, I used * as star , and you can add as many WHEN as you want to include all stars.

Comment: yes, the case solution i know but there has to be a easier way to represent the score devided with 10 and rounded to nearest even in symbols. 1-x, 2-xx, 3-xxx etc

Comment: @smtsmo Case is an easy solution and won't take much time